# VIEW creation not working after porting from MySql to SQLite code

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, view

I am porting an application and decided to port its db in a specular way in SQLite.
All the tables are working fine but the following view:

```
VIEW `view_type_questions` AS 
select `questions`.`id` AS `id_question`,
      `type_modules`.`id` AS `id_type`,
      `type_modules`.`description` AS `type_questions`
from (`questions` left join (`modules` left join `type_modules`
 on((`modules`.`id_type` = `type_modules`.`id`)))
 on((`questions`.`id_module` = `modules`.`id`)))
```

which I translated in the same exact way without apex ('):

```
 VIEW view_type_questions AS select questions.id AS
 id_question,type_modules.id AS
 id_type,type_modules.description AS type_questions
 from (questions left join (modules left join type_modules
 on((modules.id_type = type_modules.id)))
 on((questions.id_module = modules.id)))
```

gives me a weird error because when I try to execute this query I get the following:

*Error processing SQL: could not prepare statement(1 no such column: type_modules.id)*

(I am 100% sure that there are all the tables including type_modules)

1. Any way to investigate further on it?
2. Is there anything different in creating view
   between mysql and sqlite?

Comment: Please show us the create table statement of your `type_modules` table.

Comment: Works for me in SQLite 3.8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some SQLite versions have problems when you use superfluous parentheses around joins.
Just drop them (and for Zarquon's sake, format the query properly):

```
CREATE VIEW view_type_questions AS
SELECT questions.id AS id_question,
       type_modules.id AS id_type,
       type_modules.description AS type_questions
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN modules ON questions.id_module = modules.id
LEFT JOIN type_modules ON modules.id_type = type_modules.id
```